# try except error for "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" and writing to log file

Tags: python

```
try:
  os.remove('/usr/local/logs/mylog.log')
except Exception as e:
  log.error('Error: %s') %e.message
```

Running the above lines gives me `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` in the prompt and its not getting logged. I need this to be logged than this error to be displayed in the prompt.

Any suggestions..!!!

Thanks! I'm using python 2.6.6

Comment: It says "Permission denied" and it means "Permission denied". Change the file access rights or execute your script as another user.

Comment: i need that error to be logged but i couldn't catch the error through 'except' somehow. Any suggestions...!!!

Comment: Wait.. I cannot reproduce your problem. Here on my laptop the exception was handled as expected..

Comment: I don't think is the `os.remove` which triggers your `OSError`. Where are you trying to log to? You may trying to  write the log to someplace that you don't have the permission to.

Comment: Add a `print` statement immediately before the call to `log.error()`. If you see it, then it's not the `os.remove()` which is triggering the exception you're seeing, and you'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: @starrify try removing a system file from limited access user.

Comment: @onlyvinish Yes I understand that his `os.remove` may trigger an `OSError` but in his code it shall be catched..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to remove the file `/usr/local/logs/mylog.log` which most probably needs sudo permission. So run your script as `sudo python script.py` and it should work fine.

As the [error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.EACCES) says, your current user does not have permission to delete the file.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but any suggestion to handle this error through except and log it.

Comment: @onlyvinish missed this earlier, but shouldn't it be `log.error('Error: %s' %e.message)` instead of `log.error('Error: %s') %e.message`?

Comment: I tried the same, but still log is not created for this. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not only in deleting the file, it's probably also that your script doesn't have permission to write to the log file, that's why it's not getting logged, and that's why the `OSError` is not getting caught.

Comment: No, i have permission to write logs and that's not the problem too, my my except handling is not effective here. What should i do for that.?